# PHP skip the first week in calculating first/second/third Wednesday

Tags: php, date

I writing a script where it will populate a series of dates based on the criteria set between a start and finish time.

I basically using the relative formats in php dates function (http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).

My script first get the intervals based on user's selection:

```
//first get the interval
$event_repeatmonth = $_POST['event_repeatmonth'];   
if ($event_repeatmonth == 1){ $interval = 'first';}
if ($event_repeatmonth == 2){ $interval = 'second';}
if ($event_repeatmonth == 3){ $interval = 'third';}
if ($event_repeatmonth == 4){ $interval = 'fourth';}
if ($event_repeatmonth == 5){ $interval = 'fifth';}
if ($event_repeatmonth == 6){ $interval = 'last';}

$onthe_monday = $_POST['onthe_monday'];
$onthe_tuesday = $_POST['onthe_tuesday'];
$onthe_wednesday = $_POST['onthe_wednesday'];
$onthe_thursday = $_POST['onthe_thursday'];
$onthe_friday = $_POST['onthe_friday'];
$onthe_saturday = $_POST['onthe_saturday'];
$onthe_sunday = $_POST['onthe_sunday'];

if ($onthe_monday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval." Monday";}                         
if ($onthe_tuesday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval." Tuesday";}               
if ($onthe_wednesday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval." Wednesday";}               
if ($onthe_thursday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval. " Thursday";}                
if ($onthe_friday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval. " Friday";}                
if ($onthe_saturday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval. " Saturday";}                
if ($onthe_sunday == 1){ $interval_period[] = $interval. " Sunday";}
```

Then it will loop through the dates within the start and finish date. It will grab the first date of the month as the reference date and find the corresponding 1st/2nd/3rd Monday/Tuesday... of the month:

```
//loop through to insert the array
while ($tmp <= $event_udate){
    $tmpmonth = date("Y-m", strtotime($tmp))."-01";

    //get proper date based on the intervals we are looking for
    foreach ($interval_period  AS $period){
        $tmp = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($period, strtotime($tmpmonth)));
        echo $period."--".$tmp."--".$tmpmonth."<br/>";
        //sometimes the first interval will be before the start date, skip that
        if ($tmp >= $event_sdate){
            $event_datearray[] = $tmp;
        }                       
    }                   
    //reset if reach end of the month
    if ($repeat_every > 1){ 
        //go to next month      
        $tmp = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'. $repeat_every.' month',  strtotime($tmp)));                     
    }else{                              
        //go to next month      
        $tmp = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($tmp)));               
    }           
}
```

For example, here I asked the program to get the second Wednesday and the second Sunday of the month for every 3 months between the time frame of 4/1/2015 - 8/30/2015.

The result should have returned: 4/8, 4/12, 7/8, and 7/12. However, it appears that since 4/1 and 7/1 are on Wednesday, it skipped the first week and grabbed the 3rd Wednesday instead.

My echo result looks like below, as you can see, it grabbed 4/15 as the 2nd Wednesday of 2015-04-01.... and grabbed 7/15 as the 2nd Wednesday of 2015-07-01...

```
second Wednesday--2015-04-15--2015-04-01
second Sunday--2015-04-12--2015-04-01
second Wednesday--2015-07-15--2015-07-01
second Sunday--2015-07-12--2015-07-01
array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "2015-04-15" [1]=> string(10) "2015-04-12" [2]=> string(10) "2015-07-15" [3]=> string(10) "2015-07-12" }
```

I am pretty lost here. This seems to be issue only when the first of the month matches one of the criteria. If I change it to 2nd Thursday and 2nd Sunday, then it will return properly:

```
second Thursday--2015-04-09--2015-04-01
second Sunday--2015-04-12--2015-04-01
second Thursday--2015-07-09--2015-07-01
second Sunday--2015-07-12--2015-07-01
array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "2015-04-09" [1]=> string(10) "2015-04-12" [2]=> string(10) "2015-07-09" [3]=> string(10) "2015-07-12" }
```

Does anyone have the same issue before???

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after I posted it....

It turns out the relative format in PHP date DOES NOT include the date it refers to. For example, if you are looking for the 2nd Monday of 2015-04-01, it will look for the first instance of the 2nd Monday after 2015-04-01...

So to fix this, I just check to see if the first of the month matches the criteria I am looking for, if it does, then change my reference day to the day before so it will include the original date into consideration.